# Calculate time difference between POSIXct values

Tags: r, dataframe

Two cols as follows:

$ started_at        : POSIXct, format: "2020-10-31 19:39:43"

$ ended_at          : POSIXct, format: "2020-10-31 19:57:12"

So in order to calculate time (19:57:12 - 19:39:43), want to mutate new column to 00:17:29, where
ended_at - started_at

Need to change column format from POSIXct, correct??

Comment: Yes and then use `difftime` and, e.g., package hms.

Comment: Please edit your previous question rather than opening a new one.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to @Rolands comments here is a reprex:

```r
library(dplyr)
#> 
#> Attache Paket: 'dplyr'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:stats':
#> 
#>     filter, lag
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:base':
#> 
#>     intersect, setdiff, setequal, union
library(hms)


df <- tibble(
  started_at = as.POSIXct("2020-10-31 19:39:43"),
  ended_at = as.POSIXct("2020-10-31 19:57:12")
)

df <- df %>%
  mutate(time_diff = as.character(hms::as_hms(
    difftime(
      time1 = ended_at,
      time2 = started_at,
      units = "mins"
    )
  )))

df
#> # A tibble: 1 x 3
#>   started_at          ended_at            time_diff
#>   <dttm>              <dttm>              <chr>    
#> 1 2020-10-31 19:39:43 2020-10-31 19:57:12 00:17:29
```

<sup>Created on 2021-10-11 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Perfect. Now i need to have this formula in a dataframe.                                             
Tried this..                                                                                                                                 df <- tibble(
  begin_tm = as.POSIXct(cyclist_df,started_at),
  end_tm = as.POSIXct(cyclist_df,ended_at)
)                                                                                                                                                       Dataframe is cyclist_df and the 2 column names are started_at and ended_at

Comment: A tibble is nothing but a more advanced `data.frame`. So all you have to do is replace `df` from my example with `cyclist_df` and everything should work in the very same way.